# SQL Server Full Text Search and Find column

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I am currently trying to figure out how I could possibly use the full-text index to allow users to search for Keyword(s) within the DB data.  The issue I am having is that not only do I want to know the source table, but the source column as well so I can tell the user where I found the hit.

I can do it by using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA and building a large table, that I can build an index on, but then I have to keep that table in sync with the source tables.

Any other thoughts on how to do something like this?

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do separate queries?

Comment: I really don't want to have to query every table and column that would get out of hand I think.